# WordPress Hook for the Scheduled Post?

Tags: wordpress, hook

I want to trigger a function after the post is published, updated or Scheduled. I have used the `save_post` hook which works great with the Post published and update. But not working with the scheduled post.

I have tried some of the WordPress hook but it doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try the **future_to_publish** action for accomplish the task. It will help you.

```
    function scheduled_post_published($object) 
{
    // whatever it is you need to do
}
add_action('future_to_publish', 'scheduled_post_published');
```

Comment: This seems to be not working.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is to trigger the function at the moment the post is **published**, because you manually published it or you scheduled its publication for any time later, then you can use the action hook `transition_post_status`.

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'my_custom_function', 10, 3 );
function my_custom_function( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
  if ( 'publish' == $new_status ) {
    // Do something...
  }
}
```